# Issues with fminsearch in matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am having some issues with fminsearch of matlab. I have defined the TolX and TolFun as following

```
options = optimset('TolFun',1e-8, 'TolX', 1e-8)
```

Then I tried to estimate the parameters of my functions using

```
[estimates val] = fminsearch(model, start_point,options)
```

However, the val is around 3.3032e-04. Even though I specified the TolFun to be 1e-8, it still terminates before that  with value around 3.3032e-04. Actually, the desired value of the parameter is obtained at something around  1.268e-04. So I tried to set the TolFun. Why is it not working, it should have converged to the least value of the function isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other reasons for termination of the search, for example, max number of function evaluations, max number of iterations, etc.  `fminsearch` provides additional output arguments that give you information about the reason for termination.  You especially want the full `OUTPUT` argument, which provides number of iterations, termination message, etc.

```
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT] = fminsearch(...) returns a structure
OUTPUT with the number of iterations taken in OUTPUT.iterations, the
number of function evaluations in OUTPUT.funcCount, the algorithm name 
in OUTPUT.algorithm, and the exit message in OUTPUT.message.
```

Another possibility is that you've gotten stuck in local minimum.  There's not much to be done for that problem, except to choose a different start point, or a different optimizer.